# How to find probability density functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ is a random variable uniformly distributed on the real interval $[0,1]$.

Through some experimentation, I found that the probability density function, PDF of:

$X$ is $1$ or $\dfrac{d}{dx}X$

$2X$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\dfrac{d}{dx}X/2$

$3X$ is $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\dfrac{d}{dx}X/3$

$X^2$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{X}}$ or $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}$

$X^3$ is $\frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}$ or $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sqrt[3]{x}$

The PDF is useful in answering questions such as what is the mean of $X^3$ or what is the probability that $0<2x<\frac{1}{21}$?

1. How do I find the PDF of functions in general, something like $X+X^3$?
2. Also, when there is another variable involved, say Y that is a random variable uniformly distributed on the real interval [0,2], how do I find the PDF of expressions like $X+Y^2$ or $XY^2$? This is again most helpful in finding answers like what is the variance of $X+Y^2$ or what is the probability that $XY^2 > 1$?
3. What if X and Y are not uniformly distributed, but follows some continuous distribution like the Poisson or Gaussian? How do I find the PDFs in this case?

Comment: There numerous useful posts devoted to this problem: [30938](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30938), [77873](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77873), [55607](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55607) and many others.

Comment: To convince you that [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30966/6179) is for you, let me quote its first words: *The simplest and surest way to compute the distribution density or probability of a random variable is often*...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given the pdf of independent RVs $I$ and $R$, how to find cdf of $W =I^2R$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/given-the-pdf-of-independent-rvs-i-and-r-how-to-find-cdf-of-w-i2r)

Comment: I apologize but I'm not strong in calculus so I'm still having trouble understanding how to apply your solution in that particular case to the general scenario. Until I do, I'll just leave the question open, hoping someone else can answer it in a different way perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You have just discovered that the cumulutative distribution function of an $f(X)$ when $f$ is an invertible monotonuous increasing function can be computed as:

$$\mathbb{P}(f(X)<y)=\mathbb{P}(X<f^{-1}(y)) \; .$$

Comment: It is conventional to use capital $F$ for the cumulative distribution function and lower-case $f$ for the density function.  And I don't think it's a good idea to use the same letter, capital $X$, to refer both to the random variable and to the argument to the CDF.

Comment: $F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y<y)$